# elpy-importmagic-add-import without rearranging imports?

Tags: python, elpy

The auto-importing functionality of elpy is awesome. However, it rearranges all the previous import statements in the file alphabetically. This is problematic for me because:

1. I prefer to arrange my imports this way according to [pep-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)

> Imports should be grouped in the following order:
>
> > 1. standard library imports
> > 2. related third party imports
> > 3. local application/library specific imports
>
> You should put a blank line between each group of imports.

2. More importantly, I don't want the unecessary changes in my commits when existing imports are rearranged.

Is there any way to customize how imports are arranged, or to have them not be rearranged at all? I am assuming that if it doesn't rearrange them, it will not know where to put the new import, so the former option would probably be preferable. Thanks for any suggestions!

## EDIT:

On further investigation, it seems like it is *trying* to arrange imports according to pep-8, but doesn't seem to recognize my "local application/library specific imports" as such.